# Display JDialog on chosen monitor

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jdialog, multiscreen

I'm working on function which allows user to open a specific JDialog on chosen screen. I'm very close to end it, but I didn't manage one thing yet. The method below throws NullPointerException at "screen[screen].setFullScreenWindow". Although, JDialog showed up. Just after I close it NPE is jumping to my console window. I know that the problem is in the setFullScreenWindow method, but I dont't know how can I "pop" JDialog on chosen screen otherwise.

```
/*
 * SHOW ON SPECIFIC MONITOR
 */
public void showOnScreen(GraphicsDevice[] screenlist, int screen, JDialog dialog) {
     if (screen > -1 && screen < screenlist.length) {
          try {
               screenlist[screen].setFullScreenWindow(dialog);
          } catch (NullPointerException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     } else if (screenlist.length > 0) {
          screenlist[0].setFullScreenWindow(dialog);
     } else {
          throw new RuntimeException("No Screens Found");
     }
}
```

I call the method in JButton action:

```
    buttonStartDemo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      VisualField_DemoSession_JDialog dialog = new VisualField_DemoSession_JDialog();
      GraphicsDevice[] screenlist = getScreenList();
      if (screenlist.length > 1) {
           Object[] options = {"1", "2"};
           int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(new JFrame(), "On which screen you want to open Demo Session?", "Question!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
                     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[1]);
           if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                showOnScreen(screenlist, 0, dialog);
           } else if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                showOnScreen(screenlist, 1, dialog);
           }
      } else if (screenlist.length == 1) {
           showOnScreen(screenlist, 0, dialog);
      } else {
           throw new RuntimeException("No Screens Found");
      }
 }
```

});

And this is a method which gets screen list:

```
public GraphicsDevice[] getScreenList() {
 GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
 GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
 return gs;
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.awt.GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow(Unknown Source)
 at plugin.vision.visualfield.VisualField_Main_JFrame.showOnScreen(VisualField_Main_JFrame.java:349)
 at plugin.vision.visualfield.VisualField_Main_JFrame$3.actionPerformed(VisualField_Main_JFrame.java:146)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT 2013/09/30, 8:10 pm

Ok. I think I figured out what this problem was about. So mainly, I tried to call method setFullScreenWindow for "dialog" which is a object of some JDialog class. But in action of a button which calls some init methods I just initialize my "dialog". I miss one thing - proper implementation of "dialog" object class. So I did it, and NPE is gone. Simply I add main method with new Swing thread and some standard settings for contentPane. And thats it.

If you have any suggestions and if you guys can tell something more about this case I'll be very thankful.

Problem is solved. Below standard frame of JDialog class:

```
public class DialogTest extends JDialog {

 private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

 /**
  * Launch the application.
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
           DialogTest dialog = new DialogTest();
           dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
           dialog.setVisible(true);
      } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
 }

 /**
  * Create the dialog.
  */
 public DialogTest() {
      setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
      getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      contentPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 }
```

}

Comment: Show us stack trace of NPE!